# REST API: how to redirect a user to enter a password if first time logged in?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a NodeJS REST API and a react app. If the user is first time logged in I need to redirect him to a page in react where he enters new password and the login. My question is how to do that exactly ? What do I return from the API so I would know if its the first time.

What I was thinking is adding a field to my user schema example `isFirstTime` and it can be true or false, and when we try to login we check this if true log the user in, if false redirect to the new password page.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: yeah!, your solution looks perfect for me .

Answer (score 2):

Add A flag in your user schema which should be by default true, when the user logs in check if the flag is true redirect to new password page. update the password and set the flag to false.

Comment: yes that what I did. Thank you for your help.